# My variables are overwritten by the last variable every time I execute code

Tags: php, html-table, rows, overwrite

I am trying to draw a table using variables from a form but my problem is that it doesn't print anything.

```
<body>

row:<form method="post" action="prelab2.php">
<select name="row">

<option>Pick one</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
<option>8</option>
<option>9</option>
<option>10</option>

</select>
</form>
```

I have 6 different drop downs just like above, except with different values (num1,num2,num3,num4,row,columns)

Now below is the code I have that makes the table

```
<?php
$row=$_POST['row']; // define number of rows
$col=$_POST['columns']; // define number of columns

echo "<table border='5' color='purple'>";

for($tr=1;$tr<=$row;$tr++){

echo '<tr>';
    for($td=1;$td<=$col;$td++){
           echo '<td>row: '.$tr.' column: '.$td.'</td>';
    }
echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
?>
```

I want to make the table based on the variable chosen in the 'row' menu and 'columns' menu.
The problem I have run into is that it doesn't make anything. So I tried to echo the variables that it saved but no matter how many times I run it, it always posted the variable for 'columns' Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the value parameter to your option tags

`<option value='1'>1</option>`

Comment: This did work better, but it still overwrites the variables with the last one?